# Ruby:parslet for a system verilog interface parser

Tags: ruby, parslet

I am using [Ruby::Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet).

I am parsing a document similar to an SV interface, eg:

```
interface my_intf;
  protocol validonly;

  transmit  [Bool]   valid;
  transmit  [Bool]   pipeid;
  transmit  [5:0]    incr;
  transmit  [Bool]   sample;

endinterface
```

Here is my parser:

```
class myParse < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:lparen)     { space? >> str('(') >> space? }
  rule(:rparen)     { space? >> str(')') >> space? }
  rule(:lbox)       { space? >> str('[') >> space? }
  rule(:rbox)       { space? >> str(']') >> space? }
  rule(:lcurly)     { space? >> str('{') >> space? }
  rule(:rcurly)     { space? >> str('}') >> space? }
  rule(:comma)      { space? >> str(',') >> space? }
  rule(:semicolon)  { space? >> str(';') >> space? }
  rule(:eof)        { any.absent? }
  rule(:space)      { match["\t\s"] }
  rule(:whitespace) { space.repeat }
  rule(:space?)     { whitespace.maybe }
  rule(:blank_line) { space? >> newline.repeat(1) }
  rule(:newline)    { str("\n") }

  # Things
  rule(:integer)    { space? >> match('[0-9]').repeat(1).as(:int) >> space? }
  rule(:identifier) { match['a-z'].repeat(1) }


  rule(:intf_start)     { space? >> str('interface') >> space? >> (match['a-zA-Z_'].repeat(1,1) >> match['[:alnum:]_'].repeat(0)).as(:intf_name) >> space? >> str(';') >> space? >> str("\n") }
  rule(:protocol)       { space? >> str('protocol') >> whitespace >> (str('validonly').maybe).as(:protocol) >> space? >> str(';') >> space? >> str("\n") }
  rule(:bool)           { lbox >> space? >> str('Bool').as(:bool) >> space? >> rbox }
  rule(:transmit_width) { lbox >> space? >> match('[0-9]').repeat.as(:msb) >> space? >> str(':') >> space? >> match('[0-9]').repeat.as(:lsb) >> space? >> rbox }
  rule(:transmit)       { space? >> str('transmit') >> whitespace >> (bool | transmit_width) >> whitespace >> (match['a-zA-Z_'].repeat(1,1) >> match['[:alnum:]_'].repeat(0)).as(:transmit_name) >> space? >> str(';') >> space? >> str("\n") }
  rule(:interface_body) { (protocol | blank_line.maybe) }
  rule(:interface)      { intf_start >> interface_body }

  rule(:expression)     { ( interface ).repeat }

  root :expression
end
```

I am having an issue making the rule for `interface_body`.

It can have 0 or more `transmit` lines and 0 or 1 `protocol` line and multiple blanks, comments etc.

Can someone help me out please? The rules I have written in the code snippet works with single `transmit` and single `protocol`, i.e. they properly match, but when I parse a whole interface it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... this parses the file you mentioned. I don't understand the desired format so I can't say it will work for all your files, but hopefully this will get you started.

```
require 'parslet'

class MyParse < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:lparen)     { space? >> str('(') }
  rule(:rparen)     { space? >> str(')') }
  rule(:lbox)       { space? >> str('[') }
  rule(:rbox)       { space? >> str(']') }
  rule(:lcurly)     { space? >> str('{') }
  rule(:rcurly)     { space? >> str('}') }
  rule(:comma)      { space? >> str(',') }
  rule(:semicolon)  { space? >> str(';') }
  rule(:eof)        { any.absent? }
  rule(:space)      { match["\t\s"] }
  rule(:whitespace) { space.repeat(1) }
  rule(:space?)     { space.repeat(0) }
  rule(:blank_line) { space? >> newline.repeat(1) }
  rule(:newline)    { str("\n") }

  # Things
  rule(:integer)    { space? >> match('[0-9]').repeat(1).as(:int) >> space? }
  rule(:identifier) { match['a-z'].repeat(1) }

  def line( expression )
    space? >> 
    expression >>
    space? >> 
    str(';') >> 
    space? >> 
    str("\n")    
  end

  rule(:expression?)    { ( interface ).repeat(0) }

  rule(:interface)      { intf_start >> interface_body.repeat(0) >> intf_end }

  rule(:interface_body) { 
    intf_end.absent? >> 
    interface_bodyline >> 
    blank_line.repeat(0)
  }

  rule(:intf_start) { 
    line ( 
      str('interface')  >> 
      space? >> 
      ( match['a-zA-Z_'].repeat(1,1) >> 
        match['[:alnum:]_'].repeat(0)).as(:intf_name) 
    )
  }

  rule(:interface_bodyline) {
    line ( protocol | transmit )
  }

  rule(:protocol)       { 
    str('protocol') >> whitespace >> 
    (str('validonly').maybe).as(:protocol)
  }

  rule(:transmit)       {     
    str('transmit') >> whitespace >> 
    (bool | transmit_width) >> whitespace >> 
    name.as(:transmit_name)
  }

  rule(:name) {
    match('[a-zA-Z_]') >> 
    (match['[:alnum:]'] | str("_")).repeat(0)
  }

  rule(:bool)           { lbox  >> str('Bool').as(:bool) >> rbox }

  rule(:transmit_width) { 
    lbox   >> 
    space? >> 
    match('[0-9]').repeat(1).as(:msb) >> 
    space? >> 
    str(':') >> 
    space? >> 
    match('[0-9]').repeat(1).as(:lsb) >> 
    space? >> 
    rbox 
  }

  rule(:intf_end)       {  str('endinterface') }

  root :expression?
end

  require 'rspec'
  require 'parslet/rig/rspec'

  RSpec.describe MyParse  do
    let(:parser) { MyParse.new }
    context "simple_rule" do
      it "should consume protocol line" do
        expect(parser.interface_bodyline).to parse('  protocol validonly;
')
      end 
      it 'name' do
        expect(parser.name).to parse('valid')
      end
      it "bool" do
        expect(parser.bool).to parse('[Bool]')
      end 
      it "transmit line" do
        expect(parser.transmit).to parse('transmit [Bool] valid')
      end 
      it "transmit as bodyline'" do
        expect(parser.interface_bodyline).to parse('  transmit  [Bool]   valid;
')
      end 
    end
  end

  RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['--format', 'documentation'])  


begin 
  doc = File.read("test.txt")
  MyParse.new.parse(doc) 
  rescue Parslet::ParseFailed => error
    puts error.cause.ascii_tree
  end
```

The main changes...

- Don't consume whitespace both side of your tokens.
  You had expressions that parsed "[Bool] valid" as LBOX BOOL RBOX SPACE? then expected another WHITESPACE but couldn't find one (as the previous rule had consumed it).
- When an expression can validly parse as a zero length (e.g. something with repeat(0)) and there is a problem with who it's written, then you get an odd error. The rule pass and match nothing, then the next rule will typically fail. I explicitly matched 'body lines' as 'not the end line' so it would fail with an error.
- 'repeat' defaults to (0) which I would love to change. I see mistakes around this all the time.
- x.repeat(1,1) means make one match. That's the same as having x. :)
- there were more whitespace problems

so....

Write your parser from the top down. Write tests from the bottom up.
When your tests get to the top you are done! :)

Good luck.